# c# get font letter spacing

Tags: c#, fonts

I need to split a text into parts and draw the parts next to each other with a different color (like the StackExchange Logo).
However the spacing between the parts should be preserved. Is there a way to get the distance between two known letters in .NET? Fontfamily, size and a text is known.

I tried using MeasureString by measuring each part individually sum it up und substract from the MeasureString result of the total string. But the difference is a too small - the letters a are almost next to each other without space.

Comment: You need to share your code to help us understand what might be the problem. In any case, bear in mind that when dealing with control dimensioning/location there are various "side" issues to take into account (e.g., padding or dimensions of the control).

Comment: `MeasureString` has a few parameters you can try!